# Adding background in Activity makes my view seem faded

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an Activity with a ListView.I want to set as a background a simple white picture with a logo in the right lower corner.My problem is that when i set as background my picture it kinda 'sits' in front of my listView.Making the textViews seem faded.How can i effectively add a background without these side effects?Thank you for your time.

**EDIT:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg">


<dragNDropAdapter.DragNDropListView
  android:id="@+id/android:list"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</dragNDropAdapter.DragNDropListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you setting the background on the ListView? If so, what if you set it as the background of the ListView's parent? (Usually it's easier to help with these kinds of questions if you provide screenshots or snippets of code from your layout files.)

Comment: No, i set it background of the layout,aka listView's parent.I'll post the xml in a minute :)

Answer (score 0):

Put imageview & listview in relative layout.
Set attribute for your image where you want to place it and for list as well.